# Use jQuery to count the number of div's and hide button

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to tell me how many blocks are in each row and hide button class if blocks are less than 4. Currently trying this, but it doesn't give me the correct result:

```js
$('.row').each(function() {
   if ( ($(this).find('.block')).length < 4) {
      $(this).find('.button').css('display', 'none');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="block">Block1</div>
   <div class="block">Block2</div>
   <div class="block">Block3</div>
   <div class="block">Block4</div>
   <div class="block">Block5</div>
   <div class="button">Button</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="block">Block1</div>
   <div class="block">Block2</div>
   <div class="block">Block3</div>
   <div class="button">Button</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is in good condition

Comment: Well, your second button is being hidden, isn't that your expected output?

Comment: "*doesn't give me the correct result*" - so what *is* your expected/correct result as it matches the description you've given

Comment: maybe there is some logic in your code that interrupts this logic. show more code

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Yes, code seems to be ok, but he didn't hide button. For test I put alert into if tag and nothing happens. But, for example, if I change code to length > 4 then alert works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine as it is, unless I am misunderstanding your question:

```js
$('.row').each(function() {

   //a console log of the number of blocks
   console.log('Number of blocks: ' + ($(this).find('.block')).length);

   if ( ($(this).find('.block')).length < 4) {
      $(this).find('.button').css('display', 'none');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="block">Block1</div>
   <div class="block">Block2</div>
   <div class="block">Block3</div>
   <div class="block">Block4</div>
   <div class="block">Block5</div>
   <div class="button">Button</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="block">Block1</div>
   <div class="block">Block2</div>
   <div class="block">Block3</div>
   <div class="button">Button</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, $(this).find('.block')).length is working as expexted and shows correct number. But when I use If < 4 and make test alert, the code does nothing. But when I changes to If > 4 then all works. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Thewx Just tried an alert right now, and it also does work. Can you update your post showing the specific code that is not working as expected, plus your expected output?